# How do I reprogram the extra buttons of a Kensington Expert Mouse trackball under Windows 7 with left/right keys swapped?

Tags: windows-7, trackball

I've got my Expert Mouse trackball situated to my left (right hand is bugging me lately). If I just plug the thing in, it works, but I've no control over the extra two buttons. With no extra software, the one acts like clicking the scroll wheel in a regular mouse, and the other is a 'back' button.

I grabbed Kensington's software (Version 1.1.18 at the moment), and I found that it will install in Windows 7 (64 bit), BUT if I also turn on 'switch primary and secondary buttons' (which I must do, as Kensington's software supports no such thing), it acts as though the secondary button is held when I move the ball!

Prior to using the trackball, I had a Logitech mouse which had two spare buttons that ended up mapped to 'back' and 'forward' in browsers and such

Any good ideas on how to re-map the buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the logitech mouse I used apparently had it's 'back' and 'forward' buttons emitting 'mouse button 4' and 'mouse button 5', while the Kensington trackball is emitting 'middle mouse button' and 'mouse button 4'.

To rectify this, I found [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm). Using the 'Simulated Keys' option, I mapped 'Middle button' to 'Mouse Button 4' and 'Mouse Button 4' to 'Mouse Button 5'. Thus, I get my back and forward buttons where I want them on the trackball.

I suspect that if I had other mouse-type devices plugged in at the same time, I might not be happy with the result, but since I'm only using the trackball right now, it works fine.